# Neo4j aggregation all nodes with the same property values

Tags: neo4j, aggregation

I have a DB of movies

I try to create a query that returns all the movie with the same actor
for example:

Movies|Actor

Rocky,Rocky II,Rocky III,Rocky IV   | Sylvester Stallone

Comment: please run `db.schema()` command in Neo4j browser and paste response picture here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use [collect](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) function. For example, if you try neo4j [`The Movie Graph`](https://neo4j.com/developer/movie-database/):

```
MATCH (P:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(M:Movie)
RETURN P as Actor, 
       collect(M) as Movies
```

If the actor is a property, then the query can be:

```
MATCH (M:Movie)
RETURN M.MAIN_ACTOR as Actor, 
       collect(M) as Movies
```

But you need to understand that this is not in the spirit of the graph database: take the actors to separate nodes, and add relations from them to the nodes of the movies.

Comment: hi,


I dont have a ACTED_IN realationship,


in the movie nodes i have property of actor

Comment: @oshrirehani Those. Each node "Movie" has the property of an actor's name or an array of actors' names? P.S. Correct your question with an example of data.

Comment: Each node "Movie" has property of the main actor,its not a array

Comment: @oshrirehani See adding to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, but still I can point you in the right direction. Try using :

```
MATCH (a:Person{name:"Sylvester Stallone"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
RETURN a as actor,collect(m) as movies
```